# How can I eliminate syntax error in command line?

Tags: bash

How can I eliminate syntax error in command line?
I created a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER="$@"

sed 's/[!@#\$%^&*()]//g'> $@
done

if ! [ -f $@ -a -r $@ ] ; then
 echo "Wrong Option : "${USER}" is not readable or not exist" >&2
 exit -1
fi

cat "${@}"|while read -r line
do
IFS=, read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 <<< "$line"
mysql --user=user --password=password --database=database <<EOF
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES($f1,'$f2','$f3','$f4',$f5);
EOF
done
```

and I execute this script on other terminal like this:

```
$ ./script.sh test!rr.txt
-bash: !rr.txt: event not found
```

Actually, this is a script which insert data from text files to database table.
and as you can see, I want to check file existence before insert text files.

I've tried to use tr -d command and sed command to eliminate syntax error on command line, but I think it's not working..

My expectation is :

```
$ ./script.sh test!rr.txt
Wrong Option : test!rr.txt is not readable or not exist
```

Do you have any idea? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The shell is interpreting the `!` as a history command, before trying to evaluate the line. Try escaping it:

```
$ ./script.sh test\!rr.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Put quotes around your filename if you want to include bash special characters in it:

```
$ ./script.sh 'test!rr.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a case where you need to adjust your expectations. Bash is merely doing what you told it to do: perform history expansion before passing the argument to your script. The other answers about quoting the argument or otherwise escaping the "!" are all correct, but they assume you realize that history expansion is happening before the argument is passed to your script (where you can check that the file exists).

Answer (score 1):

Put the parameter in quotes to prevent the shell to interpret the special symbols:

```
$ ./script.sh "test!rr.txt"
```